# Why is this list in a JScrollPane not left aligning?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, layout-manager

I can't seem to get this to work.  I'm trying to get the list on the right to left align but it's not working and I can't seem to find the fix.

Here's what the code I have is showing:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setSize(400, 200);
        // main panel
        JPanel pan = new JPanel();
        pan.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        pan.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        jFrame.getContentPane().add(pan, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jFrame.show();
        // left panel
        JPanel left = getContentPanel();
        left.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        pan.add(left);
        // right panel (with scroll pane)
        JPanel right = getContentPanel();
        right.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        JScrollPane scr = new JScrollPane(right);
        scr.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        scr.setAlignmentX(JScrollPane.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        pan.add(scr);
    }

    private static JPanel getContentPanel() {
        JPanel rtn = new JPanel();
        rtn.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints cs = new GridBagConstraints();
        cs.gridx = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Item " + (i + 1));
            label.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            cs.gridy = i;
            rtn.add(label, cs);
        }
        rtn.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        return rtn;
    }

}
```

Comment: `GridBagLayout` is centered by default. You don't do anything to actually align to the left via the contraints.

Comment: You are aligning your entire right panel to the left, not the individual items in the panel. You can read [Oracle's Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) about GridBag and default values for GridBagConstraints.

Comment: Nice [mcve] though. 1+

Comment: Do you only want the right panel to left align? Do you want it all the way to where it meets the orange panel or just left aligned text down the center of the JScrollPane?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the purpose of alignmentx method, it doesn't do what you think

Comment: Add cs.anchor=GridBagConstraints.WEST; cs.weightx=1; cs.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL to your constraints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic answer is, `setAlignmentX` doesn't do what you think it does

Instead, you should be using the [`GridBagConstraints#anchor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#anchor) (and [`GridBagConstraints#weightx`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#weightx) constraints to change the alignment, for example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example();
    }

    public Example() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
                jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                // main panel
                JPanel pan = new JPanel();
                pan.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
                pan.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                jFrame.getContentPane().add(pan, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                // left panel
                JPanel left = getContentPanel(GridBagConstraints.CENTER);
                left.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
                pan.add(new JScrollPane(left));
                // right panel (with scroll pane)
                JPanel right = getContentPanel(GridBagConstraints.WEST);
                right.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                JScrollPane scr = new JScrollPane(right);
                scr.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                scr.setAlignmentX(JScrollPane.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
                pan.add(scr);

                jFrame.setSize(400, 400);
                jFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private static JPanel getContentPanel(int anchor) {
        JPanel rtn = new JPanel();
        rtn.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints cs = new GridBagConstraints();
        cs.gridx = 0;
        cs.anchor = anchor;
        cs.weightx = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Item " + (i + 1));
            label.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            cs.gridy = i;
            rtn.add(label, cs);
        }
        rtn.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        return rtn;
    }

}
```

Comment: Perfect! Adding these two lines gave me exactly what I was looking for:

`cs.weightx = 1;
cs.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;`